# Rolling a D6 five times; will there be at least three adjacent numbers among the results?

Tags: probability

The order in which a number appear does not matter.
How do I calculate the probability that this will happen?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle?  One possibility would be to count cases in which the three consecutive numbers begin with 1 or 2 or 3 or 4.  It seems to me that would be tricky since numbers can be repeated.  For instance, you would have to be careful about counting (1, 3, 1, 5, 2) twice for the consecutive numbers beginning with 1 case.

Answer (score 0):

There can be 3 adjacent numbers among the 5 outcomes. for example, the outcomes can be 1,2,3,4, and 6.
To find the probability, you have to find the number of such favorable outcomes over the total number of outcomes.

Comment: Is there any easy way to find these favorable outcomes, or do I just have to write them down?

Comment: Fix,1,2,3 as first 3 consecutive and count in how many ways they can appear in the outcome and do it for all the possible consecutives.

Answer (score 0):

The following Python returns 3480, so the answer is $3480/6^5 = 145/324 \approx 44.8\%$. Writing it was certainly faster and less error-prone than trying to get inclusion-exclusion or cases working.

```
from itertools import product

def three_adjacent(L):
    p = ['0']*(max(L)+1)
    for l in L:
        p[l] = '1'
    s = ''.join(p)
    return '111' in s

sum(1 for ds in product(range(1, 6+1), repeat=5) if three_adjacent(ds))
```